# If entire c# code is converted to one line and compiled would it decompile to 1 line?

Tags: c#

So yeah im just wondering, if some c# code is converted to one line and its compiled, would the code that was converted to 1 line decompile to one line?

e.g. Original code:

```
if(blahblah=="123")
{
    //do something
}
```

e.g Code converted to one line:

```
if(blahblah=="123")
{
    //do something
    //if this is compiled; would it decompile to one line or would it 
    //Decompile to the Original code shown above?
}
```

Comment: Decompiled by what?  Why does it matter?

Comment: Not necessarily... but why do you bother about that?

Comment: Decompilers can use whatever rules they want to generate equivalent source code - most will probably use brackets on separate lines since that's standard practice for source code, but there are no decompiler "standards: that say that they have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c#.net compiles to MSIL. In MSIL both examples are represented exactly the same. Something along the lines of

```
load variable blahblah
load constant 123
compare for equality
```

MSIL doesn't care about whitespace. Decompilers simply translate MSIL back to C#. Both examples would decompile the same, since they both generate the same MSIL

Comment: Thanks! Exactly the answer i was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no such thing as "lines" recorded in the CIL produced by compilation, a decompiler like ILSpy etc. won't match the number of lines in the original.

It will also differ in spacing, names of locals, patterns (switch is sometimes compiled as if-else chains so the decompiler can at best guess if something should be decompiler to switch or if), common idioms not used (if you code an explicit mixture of using, GetEnumerator, MoveNext and Current, how's the decompiler going to know you hadn't used a normal foreach?), and even the very presence of code, for if the compiler skips a dead branch then it doesn't exist in the CIL to decompile back).

Debug information will make a decompilation more faithful if present and if the decompiler uses it.

Comment: @MickyD but of course only, "…if the decompiler uses it."